# How to correctly use scrapys LinkExtractor

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape items from a website called willys (https://www.willys.se/). I want to reach all links within the website with "sortiment/" in the url.
But I can't seem to get allow=r"sortiment/" (https://www.willys.se/sortiment/) to work, the bot will simply stop at the bot and main webpage.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = ["https://www.willys.se/"]
    allowed_domains = ["www.willys.se"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"sortiment/"), callback="parse", follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        print("Parsing URL:", response.url)
        
        with open('response_content.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
            f.write(soup.prettify())
```

calling the spider

```
scrapy crawl spider
```

This is the output

```
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.9.0 started (bot: my_project_name)
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.3.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.2.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023), cryptography 41.0.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 0.5,
 'BOT_NAME': 'my_project_name',
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'my_project_name.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['my_project_name.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5130cc64f37e65de
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-08-02 16:21:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-08-02 16:21:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-08-02 16:21:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-08-02 16:21:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.willys.se/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-08-02 16:21:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.willys.se/> (referer: None)
2023-08-02 16:21:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-08-02 16:21:34 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 436,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 106051,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 5.879534,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 2, 14, 21, 34, 884435),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 405009,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 2, 14, 21, 29, 4901)}
2023-08-02 16:21:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I have tried with other websites using the same logic, and made it work. Is there something about the webadress that dosen't match? If I leave of the allow (allow=None) it returns all the websites on the page.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried swapping to other websites to see if I would be experiancing the same issue, but that dosen't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Those Links are not in the first response, the site makes a request to `https://www.willys.se/leftMenu/categorytree` to get these. Once you parse this response as a dictionary you can get the links with something like:

```
[urljoin(https://www.willys.se/, "/sortiment/"+ children["url"]) for children in parsed_response["children"]]
```

Comment: What do mean? I want to request from the website. How do this website differ from an example website bookstoscrape.com? Sorry, I’m maybe not that familiar with HTML

Comment: Some sites don't get all their data in one single request, for example willys.se loads menus info or products info in other requests but in the bookstoscrape case all the data is present in the first request. You can use scrapy's base spider (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider) and not crawlspider for this case. To find these other requests you can use the inspect network tab in your browser's developer tools and filter the requests by Fetch/XHR.